# Will writing MSC instead of MSc in an application count against me?

Tags: graduate-admissions, masters, application, errors-erratum

I am really stressing out over masters applications and I have realized I have stupidly made a minor error. Instead of writing MSc I wrote MSC and I was not consistent. 
Would the admissions tutor care?

Comment: Almost certainly not.

Comment: That's good to hear. The stress of trying to get into a MSc program is killing me :(

Comment: If they do, do you really want to go to such an institution?

Comment: @user99865 `The stress of trying to get into a MSc program is killing me :(` If you want to be successful in your academic life, first learn to be relaxed instead of being this much nervous. Calm down and relax. Nervousness will not help you find better programs and it will not help your application progress.

Answer (score 6):

While it is possible for an applicant to be harmed by sufficiently bad grammar in a personal statement, I cannot imagine something on the scale that you describe -- writing MSC instead of MSc -- having any impact whatsoever on the evaluation of your application. Bad grammar can count against you because it indicates that you are not be a poor writer and/or you didn't take time and care with your application. Switching between MSc and MSC signals neither of these things, so you should be fine. There are so many ways to sell or sink an application that something on this scale is miniscule noise compared to the other signals that an application provides.

Note, by the way, that there is some [variation allowed](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/102728/whats-the-correct-way-of-writing-a-higher-education-title-msc-or-m-sc) in this abbreviation, though I don't think MSC is among the accepted forms.